# construction of a discrete family

Tags: general-topology

**Question**: Let $\mathcal{A}=\{A_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ be a discrete family of closed sets in a normal space $X$. Then can we find a discrete family $\mathcal{W}=\{W_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ of regular closed sets in $X$ such that $A_\alpha \subseteq W_\alpha$, for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$.

***Definition***: (i) $\mathcal{A}$ is said to be discrete family if for each $x\in X$ there is an open set which cuts at most one member of $\mathcal{A}$.
(ii) $A\subseteq X$ is regular closed if $A=cl(int(A))$. Note that $int(cl(A)) =X\setminus cl(int(A))$ and for any open set $A, A\subseteq int(cl(A))\subseteq cl(int(A))$

***Observation***: (i)In a normal space two disjoint regular closed set can be separated by two disjoint regular open set.
(ii)In a normal space, for a discrete family $\{A_\alpha\}$ of regular closed sets not necessarily one can find a discrete family of open sets $\{O_\alpha\}$ such that $A_\alpha \subseteq O_\alpha$.
That is, if the above result is true that does not hamper normality and collectionwise normality of a space.  (ii) Result is obvious when $\Lambda$ is finite and I guess it can be done upto $\Lambda$ is countable. I can't find what to do when $\Lambda$ is uncountable, please help.

Comment: The result is true if $A$ is countable  . All I know about normal spaces that are not collection-wise normal is that they are hard to find. E.g. Bing space ("Bing's Example").

Comment: For any open set $A$ not necessarily $A=int(cl(A))$. For instance, if $A\ne X$ is a dense open subset of a space $X$ then $A\ne int(cl(A))=X$.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake@AlexRavsky . I have corrected it. Please have a look again. Your comment is valuable to me.

Comment: OK, I'm looking. I was not notified about your comment probably because you typed "mistake@AlexRavsky" without a space.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the definition of a discrete family is the usual one, that is, $\mathcal A$ is discrete if and only if for each $x \in X$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ which intersects at most one element of $\mathcal A$, there are at least consistent examples where such a discrete expansion does not exist.  Assume $2^{\aleph_1} = 2^{\aleph_0}$. (This assumption follows, for example, from Martin's Axiom plus the denial of the Continuum Hypothesis.) Then there is a separable normal space $X$ having an uncountable closed discrete subset.  The singletons in the subset form a discrete uncountable family, but since the space is separable, and, therefore, does not have an uncountable collection of disjoint open subsets, there is not a collection $\mathcal W$ of the sort asked for.

Comment: Thanks for your point. But in my case it is $2^{\mathbb{N}_0} \subset 2^{\mathbb{N}_1}$.

Comment: For consistent examples of separable normal spaces $X$ with $e(X) =\frak c$ , see, for instance, R. Levy, M. Matveev *Weak extent in normal spaces*, Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin. **46**:3 (2005), 497–501.

Answer (score 1):

> **Lemma.** Let $X$ be a topological space, $U\subseteq X$ be open and $D=cl(U)$. Then $cl(int(D))=D$. In other words closures of open subsets are regular closed.

*Proof.* "$\subseteq$" Let $x\in cl(int(D))$. Then for any open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ we have $V\cap int(D)\neq\emptyset$. Since $int(D)\subseteq cl(U)$ then $V\cap cl(U)\neq\emptyset$ and thus $x\in cl(U)$.

"$\supseteq$" Note that $U\subseteq D$ and since $U$ is open then $U\subseteq int(D)$. In particular $D=cl(U)\subseteq cl(int(D))$. $\Box$

---

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a discrete family of closed subsets. Let me restate the definition of a discrete family (correct me if I'm wrong): there is a family $\mathcal{U}$ of open subsets such that

- for each $A\in\mathcal{A}$ there is $U\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $A\subseteq U$
- $U\cap V=\emptyset$ for $U,V\in\mathcal{U}$, $U\neq V$

Pick $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and the corresponding $U\in\mathcal{U}$ (i.e. $A\subseteq U$). Put $F:=X\backslash U$. Then $A\cap F=\emptyset$ and since both are closed (and $X$ is normal) then we can separate them with open neighbourhoods $U_A$ and $U_F$ respectively. Define $W_A:=cl(U_A)$.

1. Obviously $A\subseteq W_A$.
2. $\mathcal{W}=\{W_A\}_{A\in\mathcal{A}}$ is discrete. Indeed $W_A\cap F=\emptyset$ ($F$ defined earlier) and since both are closed we can separate them by $U_{W_A}$ and $U'_F$. The family $U_{W_A}$ is what we are looking for.
3. Since each $W_A$ is a closure of an open subset then it is regular closed by the lemma.

Comment: 2nd part of the restated definition of a discrete family   
$\bullet   U\cap V =\phi$ for $U,V\in \mathcal{U}, U\neq V$
is not always true. However in a normal space if $\mathcal{A}$ is countable then this is true.   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
  

If we assume $\mathcal{A}$ is countable. Then   
   
 $2. \mathcal{W}=\{W_A\}$ is discrete. Could you please elaborate. As I can see $\cup \mathcal{W}$ is not necessarily closed. For $x\not\in \cup \mathcal{W}$, what will be the required open set.

Comment: @Manik I'm not sure I understand. I think you have to precisely explain the definition of discrete family. What does "if for each $x\in X$ there is an open set which cuts at most one member of $\mathcal{A}$" mean? Because if it doesn't mean what I have "restated" then I don't what it means.

Comment: According to your restated definition of discrete family, how  is $\mathcal{W}=\{W_A\}$ discrete? Please explain. @freakish

Comment: @Manik I recall that a family of subsets of a topological space $X$ is discrete if every point $x\in X$ has a neighborhood that intersects at most one set of a given family (see, for instance, Ryszard Engelking’s “General Topology” (2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989), 1.1.10 at p.16).

Answer (score 0):

If the family $\mathcal A$ is countable then a positive answer follows from a positive answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054519/normal-space-and-discrete-family) question.

If the family $\mathcal A$ is uncountable then an answer, in general, is negative even in ZFC. Indeed, let $X$ be the space constructed below in Example J (see [T, $\S $2, p. 713]), the referenced Junilla’s work is [J].

[image]

I recall that a space is *$\aleph_1$-collectionwise Hausdorff* if for each its discrete family $\mathcal{A}=\{\{x_\alpha\} : \alpha <\aleph_1 \}$ of *one-point* sets  there exists a  family $\mathcal{V}=\{V_\alpha : \alpha<\aleph_1\}$ of *disjoint* open sets such that $x_\alpha\in V_\alpha$ for each $\alpha<\aleph_1$. A space satisfies *countable chain condition* provided each its family of non-empty disjoint open sets is (at most) countable.

Now let $\mathcal{A}$ be the family violating $\aleph_1$-collectionwise Hausdorffness of the space $X$. Assume that $\mathcal{W}=\{W_\alpha : \alpha<\aleph_1\}$ is a discrete a family of regular closed sets in $X$ such that $x_\alpha\in W_\alpha$ for each $\alpha<\aleph_1$. Then $\mathcal{W’}=\{\operatorname{int} W_\alpha : \alpha<\aleph_1\}$ is an uncountable family of non-empty disjoint open subsets of the space $X$, a contradiction.

References

[J] H.J.K. Junilla *Countability of point ﬁnite families of sets*, Canad. J. Math. 31 (1979), 673–679.

[T] Gary Gruenhage *Normality versus collectionwise normality*, p. 685-732 in: K.Kunen, J.E.Vaughan (eds.) *[Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology](https://mega.co.nz/#!okIAFI7R!2tyL2hwysmN_Y-h-iOizIykIZdrEP5jlfNFn8BdINso)*, Elsevier Science Publishers B.V., 1984.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Ravsky for providing such nice example. I have two question,   
(i) Is the family $\mathcal{A}=\{\{x_\alpha\} : \alpha <\mathbb{N}_1\}$ countable?   
(ii) $\mathcal{W}$ is discrete then $\mathcal{W}^{'}$ is discrete, fine. But $x_\alpha \in W_\alpha$, is it always imply $x_\alpha \in int W_\alpha$?

Comment: Ohh, $\mathcal{A}$ is uncountable, that i have understood. Please tell me the second one?

Comment: @Manik No, it does not  imply that $x_\alpha\in W_\alpha$, but it implies that $W_\alpha$ is non-empty, and so is its interior, and this does the trick.

Comment: Correct me! what I understand, $\mathcal{A}$ is a discrete family of point closed set which can not be separated by open sets. If the stated result is true, we can find $\mathcal{W}^{'}$ which gives a separation of $\mathcal{A}$ by open (int$W_\alpha$) sets...which is a contradiction! But since $x_\alpha \notin int W_\alpha$ so there is no contradiction (i.e., $\mathcal{W}^{'}$ is not able to separate $\mathcal{A}$). Then how does the trick work?

Comment: @Manik No, it is not essential that members of the family $\mathcal A$ cannot be separated by open sets. It is essential that there exists such a discrete family of closed sets. We obtain a contradiction assuming that members of $\mathcal A$ can be inflated to regular closed sets.

Comment: Since $X$ is not $N_1$-collectionwise Hausdorff, there exists a family $\mathcal{A}=\{\{x_\alpha\} : \alpha<\mathbb{N}_1 \}$ which can not be separated by open sets. To get the contradiction, using stated result, we have to find a discrete family $\mathcal{W}^{'}$ of open set which separates $\mathcal{A}$. Here $\mathcal{W}^{'}$ is not able to separate $\mathcal{A}$, so here is no contradiction.   Please specify which discrete family of closed sets can not be separated and what is the contradiction? kindly explain in detail.

Comment: @Manik I don’t know which discrete family $\mathcal A$ of one-point sets can not be separated (in fact, it was not explicitly provided in the example sketch), but we know that it exists, because otherwise the space $X$ would be $\aleph_1$-collectionwise Hausdorff. Using this family we can find an uncountable family of non-empty disjoint open subsets of the space X, which yields a contradiction, because the space $X$ satisfies the countable chain condition.